# C++: Fastest way to merge and split a uint into 4 bytes

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, binary, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Method to Split a 32 Bit number into Bytes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741212/fastest-method-to-split-a-32-bit-number-into-bytes-in-c)

Is there a way to merge/split a uint into 4 bytes quicker than what I'm currently doing? Maybe some inline assembler that has a native opcode that can do it in a single instruction?

```
// merge into x0
unsigned int x0 = (data[i] << 24) | (data[i+1] << 16) | (data[i+2] << 8) | data[i+3]; 


// split x0
outputBuffer[i] = (x0 >> 24);
outputBuffer[i+1]  = (x0 >> 16) & 0xFF;
outputBuffer[i+2]  = (x0 >> 8) & 0xFF;
outputBuffer[i+3]  = (x0) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: This kind of micro-optimization is far too sensitive to the context that uses it. There's a lot of ways to do this, and no single one will always be the fastest.

Comment: Pity you tagged this with "Visual-C++". In a more general case, the order in which you do the concatenation sometimes have an effect on the performance. For 16 bit architectures it is better to join the two lower bytes, and the two upper ones, forming two 16 bit values, which you later could join.

Answer (score 0):

You can write them directly into a char, no shifting needed (no idea what this will do with the generated assembly though, but `gcc -S` might help you there):

```
  unsigned int i = 0x12345678;

  char LSB = *((char*)&i);
  char MSB = *((char*)&i+3);
```

Comment: Ouch, this is 1) endian-dependent and 2) probably more inefficient as most compilers would place `i` on the stack rather than keeping in a processor register.

Comment: @Lindydancer, as said in the comments of the question, it is too sensitive. You could of course use code to make sure `i` is not put on the stack. My point was just that it is possible to do it without shifting, but copy the bytes directly from the integer.